# How to fetch data in different arrays with PHP and SQLite?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, sqlite

I am trying to fetch data from different tables but is showing nothing in arrays. If I am going to comment one of the results is showing one of the arrays.

```
$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$items = $result->fetchAll();
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM 'types'
        ORDER BY 'id'";

$result = $objDb->query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    throw new PDOException("Error Processing Request");

}

$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$types = $result->fetchAll();
// $clients = $result->fetchAll();
```

Here is showing only the 'types' table. If I change FROM 'types' to FROM 'clients' and I will comment the $types = $result line will show the 'clients' table but I want to show both. How can I do this?

Comment: You either need 2 queries, 1 for each table, or if the data in both tables is related then JOIN them in the query.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're only able to display one table's data is that you're setting the $result variable twice. If you get one table's values, then immediately after that you get another table's values, you'll overwrite the result from the first table. You need to store the result first, then get new results, then you can use the stored results when you need them.

Perform a separate query for the 'clients' table.